# ansible: set fact with multiple values

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

i am writing an ansible role for setting some kind of "hostgroups" based on outputs from commands, path etc..
thing is one host can be a member of more then one of such groups, and there is the problem. how to i append multiple values to one particular fact, without using a gazillion of different variables for the groups, as this list might get really long.

best would be a list like this:

"itsv_hostgroup": {WBG,LNZ,...}

---

i ended up with the following solution. there are same smart guys over there at the ansible google group and they dont consider themself to good to provide some useful example code.

```
- set_fact:
        itsv_hostgroup: '{{ itsv_hostgroup | default([]) + ["LNZ"] }}'
        cacheable: true
  when: (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,02781A6BX") or
        (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,02781A6CX") or
        (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,02781A6DX")
- debug:
    var: itsv_hostgroup

- set_fact:
        itsv_hostgroup: '{{ itsv_hostgroup | default([]) + ["WBG"] }}'
        cacheable: true
  when: (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,022199BF7")
- debug:
    var: itsv_hostgroup

- set_fact:
        itsv_hostgroup: '{{ itsv_hostgroup | default([]) + ["GBG"] }}'
        cacheable: true
  when: (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,022199BB7")
- debug:
    var: itsv_hostgroup

- set_fact:
        itsv_hostgroup: '{{ itsv_hostgroup | default([]) + ["VIE"] }}'
        cacheable: true
  when: (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,022199BF7") or
        (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "022199BB7") or
        (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,02060CE6R")

- debug:
    var: itsv_hostgroup
```

in this example the WBG value is overwritten by the VIE value in the end.

```
    - shell: /usr/bin/uname -L | cut -d ' ' -f2
      register: itsv_lparname

    - command: /usr/sbin/lsattr -El sys0 -a systemid -F value
      register: itsv_machine_serial

    - set_fact:
            itsv_hostgroup: "LNZ"
            cacheable: true
      when: (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,02781A6BX") or
            (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,02781A6CX") or
            (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,02781A6DX")
    - debug:
        var: itsv_hostgroup

    - set_fact:
            itsv_hostgroup: "WBG"
            cacheable: true
      when: (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,022199BF7")
    - debug:
        var: itsv_hostgroup

    - set_fact:
            itsv_hostgroup: "GBG"
            cacheable: true
      when: (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,022199BB7")
    - debug:
        var: itsv_hostgroup

    - set_fact:
            itsv_hostgroup: "VIE"
            cacheable: true
      when: (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,022199BF7") or
            (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "022199BB7") or
            (itsv_machine_serial.stdout is match "IBM,02060CE6R")
    - debug:
        var: itsv_hostgroup



root@lpgaixmgmtlx01:/etc/ansible/aix>ansible-playbook -i AIXWUKIT, testplay.yml

PLAY [run test play] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [AIXWUKIT]

TASK [hostgroups : shell] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [AIXWUKIT]

TASK [hostgroups : command] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [AIXWUKIT]

TASK [hostgroups : set_fact] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [AIXWUKIT]

TASK [hostgroups : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [AIXWUKIT] => {
    "itsv_hostgroup": []
}

TASK [hostgroups : set_fact] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [AIXWUKIT]

TASK [hostgroups : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [AIXWUKIT] => {
    "itsv_hostgroup": "WBG"
}

TASK [hostgroups : set_fact] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [AIXWUKIT]

TASK [hostgroups : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [AIXWUKIT] => {
    "itsv_hostgroup": "WBG"
}

TASK [hostgroups : set_fact] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [AIXWUKIT]

TASK [hostgroups : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [AIXWUKIT] => {
    "itsv_hostgroup": "VIE"
}

TASK [print out the hostname of target] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [AIXWUKIT]
```

Comment: ok, an list than...

Comment: elaborate how the mentioned duplicate answers my question? i do not want to use a different variable for each group or something like that.  i just want know how to add add multiple values to a fact.

Comment: Here is my elaboration: it answers very accurately. Particularly the second answer under the dup-target. You just copy, paste, and replace variable names with yours.

Comment: not for me, it seems. there not even a set_fact in the answer...hmmm

Comment: Judging from the difference of timestamps between my comment and yours, it took you 85 seconds to copy the code, paste, replace the values, and test. Am I correct in my calculation? Oh, and include writing your comment.

Comment: for curiosity's sake i did the the copy/paste and as expected a total train wreck. fatal: [AIXWUKIT]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ itsv_hostgroup + [itsv_hostgroup] if itsv_hostgroup else itsv_hostgroup }}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"}

Comment: You wanted to add a value to `itsv_hostgroup`, so you need to replace `[itsv_hostgroup]` in your expression with the value you want to add.